# Why is my SSJS block to update a query definition suddenly not working

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ampscript

I'm running an automation, and one of the steps is to take the latest entry from a date stamped data extension, use the value from the 'jobno' field and update a query definition with it. The query definition is

```
SELECT * FROM Media_Master WHERE Job_Ref = 'ABC_12345_HIS_B60_01'
```

Where the target data extension is the same as the Job_Ref value, and is an overwrite query.

The SSJS block I'm using to update it is:

```
<script runat="server">
    Platform.Load("Core","1.1.1");
    var stream = ContentAreaByName("UM_GetJobNo");
    Write(TreatAsContent(stream));    
</script>

Job No. Received...

<script runat=server>
Platform.Load("Core","1");
var qd = QueryDefinition.Init("UM_Populate");
var deName = Variable.GetValue("@jobno");
var status = qd.Update({
    Name : "UM_Populate",
TargetUpdateType : "Overwrite",
TargetType : "DE",
Target : {
    Name : (deName),
    CustomerKey : (deName)
},
    QueryText : "SELECT * FROM Media_Master WHERE Job_Ref = '".concat(deName).concat("'")
    });
qd.Perform();
</script>
Congrats, population starts here
```

Now this used to work perfectly, and I know the UM_GetJobNo is working as I tested it in a microsite and printed the variable it was supposed to fetch, and it worked fine, but now it's not - I can't figure out why. I don't get an error and the automation appears to run successfully, but the query has not updated. Any help?

Comment: Have you renamed anything lately? Sometimes renaming a DE or creating a new one with the same name can cause things to go bonkers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please contact Salesforce. SSJS has not being working for me since the release last week. There seems an issue with Salesforce.

Comment: Thanks - it seems to be working now, I saw another thread here on SFSE and the comments on it mentioned that it had now been fixed - and now it works.

Comment: has yours stopped working again? I am now experiencing the same issue.

Comment: nope, it has been fine since then.